# How to sort posts read from JSON server file in Swift

Tags: json, sorting, swift

I want to sort the posts I read from JSON file on the server.

I want to sort via push of a button, sorted by name or time

My code

```
func ReadFromJson()
{
    let path="www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/.json"
    let url=NSURL(string: path)
    let session=NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task=session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, err) -> Void in

        if (err == nil)
        {
            let dic = 
                 NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, 
                     options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil) 
                     as NSDictionary

            self.arr=dic["events"] as? NSArray
            self.MyCollection.reloadData()
            self.Myind.stopAnimating()                
        }            
    })        
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We would need to see more detail on the structure of the `events` array, but if you're going to use `NSArray`, then you'd use one of the many `NSArray` sorting methods.

First, let's assume that the JSON looked like:

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "name": "Storming of the Bastille",
            "date": "July 7, 1789"
        },
        {
            "name": "american revolution",
            "date": "July 4, 1776"
        },
        {
            "name": "Guy Fawkes Night",
            "date": "November 5, 1605"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you wanted to sort that by name, you could:

```
var error: NSError?
if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &error) as? NSDictionary {
    if let unsortedEvents = json["events"] as? NSArray {
        let descriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true, selector: "caseInsensitiveCompare:")
        self.events = unsortedEvents.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([descriptor])
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

Clearly, if the dates were in a form that could be sorted alphabetically, you could do something like the above. I picked formats that were not in an easily sorted form, to illustrate a more complicated combination of `NSDateFormatter` and `sortedArrayUsingComparator`

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, YYYY"

var error: NSError?
if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &error) as? NSDictionary {
    if let unsortedEvents = json["events"] as? NSArray {
        self.events = unsortedEvents.sortedArrayUsingComparator() { (obj1, obj2) -> NSComparisonResult in
            let event1 = obj1 as NSDictionary
            let event2 = obj2 as NSDictionary

            let date1 = formatter.dateFromString(event1["date"] as NSString)
            let date2 = formatter.dateFromString(event2["date"] as NSString)

            return date1!.compare(date2!)
        }
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

Comment: But I want when a button is pushed appears sort options by name, date, or time

Comment: Fine, so just re-sort the array depending upon which button was clicked.