# Sorting Array of Dictionary getting from snapshot.value using Firebase SDK in swift 3.1

Tags: ios, swift3

I have an array which contains data as while fetching through firebase sometimes data come in proper sequence while some time randomly. So, needed to sort my local array using sorting method

Repsonse from snapshot.value :

```
    Optional({
    Images =     {
        "-KmRCabAyzoVNMD06Hpr" =         {
            UploadTime = 1497269431993;
            imageUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mychat-1147d.appspot.com/o/Images%2FwRHmnmfu3CeqXa77YgHEWVXI1AI3%2F518962226641.jpg?alt=media&token=645878ac-1124-44b0-8203-75e94813ca76";
        };
        "-KmRCnYSsjJaZ3RINRDG" =         {
            UploadTime = 1497269484338;
            imageUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mychat-1147d.appspot.com/o/Images%2FwRHmnmfu3CeqXa77YgHEWVXI1AI3%2F518962275721.jpg?alt=media&token=d0113b12-531c-48a5-838b-02f96396a6df";
        };
        "-KmRCweslwMPBt0aCBIc" =         {
            UploadTime = 1497269521676;
            imageUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mychat-1147d.appspot.com/o/Images%2FwRHmnmfu3CeqXa77YgHEWVXI1AI3%2F518962317708.jpg?alt=media&token=e931d9b3-5635-4e2f-a597-2c60aa25b38d";
        };
        "-KmRD13t3pI21ci45LEv" =         {
            UploadTime = 1497269544342;
            imageUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mychat-1147d.appspot.com/o/Images%2FwRHmnmfu3CeqXa77YgHEWVXI1AI3%2F518962340349.jpg?alt=media&token=a738df76-e00b-48c2-9983-1e902e285a5f";
        };
        "-KmRD6WfaNTgKaVhy_Iq" =         {
            UploadTime = 1497269566141;
            imageUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mychat-1147d.appspot.com/o/Images%2FwRHmnmfu3CeqXa77YgHEWVXI1AI3%2F518962359997.jpg?alt=media&token=5828ee44-1721-4267-99d7-91f10381aa13";
        };
        "-KmREsVwMb4sY6yN4pNK" =         {
            UploadTime = 1497270028928;
            imageUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mychat-1147d.appspot.com/o/Images%2FwRHmnmfu3CeqXa77YgHEWVXI1AI3%2F518962824146.jpg?alt=media&token=aa0383c7-7d26-4b7a-b9bb-dbb1da3cdfff";
        };
    };
    UserInfo =     {
        UserID = wRHmnmfu3CeqXa77YgHEWVXI1AI3;
        userName = "Aric D'sooza";
    };
   })
```

I need to sort this array according to UploadTime.

I have tried this:

```
let sortedArray = (myArray ).sorted(by: { (dictOne, dictTwo) -> Bool in
        let d1 = dictOne["UploadTime"]! as! Double
        let d2 = dictTwo["UploadTime"]! as! Double

        return d1 < d2
    })
    print("Sorted Array - %@",sortedArray)
}
```

and also tried:

```
self.sortedArray = (myArray as NSArray).sortedArray(using: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "UploadTime", ascending: true)]) as! [[String:AnyObject]]
```

Comment: your JSON is not in correct format, could you share the valid JSON and also the code you tried

Comment: i have edited my question.

Comment: The value for key `Images` is a dictionary. A dictionary is unordered by definition.

Comment: But we can sort dictionary like :                                                                    
let sortedKeys = Array(dictionary.keys).sorted(<)

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351026/how-to-sort-json-coming-from-alamofire-and-return-final-json-object-swiftyjson

Comment: Do one thing, enumerate myArray and store all dictionaries in one local array then try to sort that array as you did in above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code , It worked for me.

```
 func sortDictonary(aDataDict:[String:AnyObject]) ->[[String:Any]] {

        let allKeys = Array(aDataDict.keys)
        var arrImages = [[String:Any]] ()
        for key in allKeys{
            var aDict = aDataDict[key] as! [String:AnyObject]    
            let aTempData = ["uploadTime" :aDict["UploadTime"] as! Double,
                                 "imageUrl":aDict["imageUrl"] as! String,
                                 "AutoId": key] as [String : AnyObject]
                // Here AutoID is unique key from your Response e.g. -KmREsVwMb4sY6yN4pNK
                arrImages.append(aTempData)
        }
        return arrImages
    }
```

Call this function and pass your `Images Dictionary` as ,

```
var aDataDict = yourJSONResponse as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
var aDictUserInfo = aDataDict["UserInfo"] as!Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
let aDictImages = aDataDict["Images"] as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
let arrTempImages :[[String:Any]]  = self.sortDictonary(aDataDict: aDictImages)
```

You will get sorted array as,

```
arrImagesData = (arrImagesData as NSArray).sortedArray(using: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "uploadTime", ascending: true)]) as! [[String:AnyObject]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
var localArray : [[String : AnyObject]] = [[:]]

for dic in myArray{
localArray.append(dic)
}

let sortedArray = (localArray ).sorted(by: { (dictOne, dictTwo) -> Bool in
        let d1 = dictOne["UploadTime"]! as! Double
        let d2 = dictTwo["UploadTime"]! as! Double

        return d1 < d2
    })
    print("Sorted Array - %@",sortedArray)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Images` key's associated value is a *dictionary* not an array, and dictionaries cannot be sorted *per se*. You have some choices, including:

1. If the keys (`"-KmRCabAyzoVNMD06Hpr"`) are unimportant to you then convert your dictionary into an array and then sort that array. Your comparison function in the question can be used for this.
2. Make a collection of the keys and sort those according to the `UploadTime` key value in the dictionary they refer to.

(2) may sound complicated but you have the parts you need in your question and subsequent comment:

> But we can sort dictionary like : let sortedKeys = Array(dictionary.keys).sorted(<)

That doesn't sort the dictionary, it sorts the dictionary's keys. But you do not wish to sort the keys by their values but according to what they refer to - the element dictionaries - and you have written a function along those lines, you just need to combine the two:

```
let orderedKeys = Images.keys.sorted(by: { (keyOne, keyTwo) -> Bool in
   let d1 = Images[keyOne]!["UploadTime"] as! Int
   let d2 = Images[keyTwo]!["UploadTime"] as! Int
   return d1 < d2
})
```

This takes the keys (`keyOne`), obtains the dictionary they refer to (`Images[keyOne]!`), and the value in that dictionary you wish to sort by (`["UploadTime"] as! Int` *[my test data contained integers]*), and compares those.

Note that the original dictionary, `Images`, is not sorted at all; rather you have a collection, `orderedKeys`, which contains the keys in the order you want to deal with the values in the dictionary. To get the first element in your sort you take the first key in `orderedKeys` and use that to index `Images`.

You could make an array using `orderedKeys`, or just print out the values so you know its working:

```
for key in orderedKeys
{
   print(Images[key] ?? "should never occur")
}
```

HTH